# Apply class to parent row, if child cell contains a specific value

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, wordpress

## Problem

I want to hide a row if a value appears in any of its child cells.

## Desired Effect

- Apply class to row, if one of its child cells contains a specific value
- Bonus Challenge: Hide column containing the value, i.e. "admin-hide"

## Example Code

```
$('tr').each(function(){
if($('td:contains("non-member")', this).length{       
$(this).addClass('disabled');
}
});
```

## Why?

Invaluable for tables containing information that needs to be:

- toggled on/off without losing the back-end data, i.e. member roster,
  with lapsed member rows having display: none;
- highlighting particular rows, i.e. premium sponsors

## Difficulties I've Faced

Hiding the column is problematic. If necessary, I can stick to just have hiding rows with child elements containing a string.

## Tech I've Working w/

- Wordpress 3.5.1
- Jquery 1.10.1
- Tablepress Pluging (which uses DataTables plugin for Jquery)

## Attempt #1

This is what I have in the page editor in WordPress:

```
[table id=3 /]
<script>jQuery(function($) {
$('#tableID tr').filter(function() {
$('td', this).each(function() {
if ($(this).text().indexOf('admin-hide') != -1)
$('#tableID tr td:eq('+ $(this).index() +')').hide();
});

return $(this).text().indexOf('non-member') != -1;
}).addClass('disabled');
});</script>
<style>
.disabled {display: none;}
</style>
```

## Attempt #2 - @adeneo

This hides the row but breaks Datatables/Tablepress:

```
<script> jQuery(function($) {
$('#tablepress-3 tr:contains("admin-hide")').addClass('disable-cells')
var index = $('td:contains("admin-hide")').index();
$('th,td', '#tablepress-3').filter('nth-child('+(index+1)+')').addClass('disable-cells'); });
</script>
<style>
.disable-cells {display: none;}
</style>
```

## Attempt #3 - @SpenserJ

This hides the row, allows for Datatables. However, it doesn't hide the column.

```
<script>
jQuery(function($) {
$('#tablepress-3 td').each(function() {
if ($(this).text().indexOf('admin-hide') !== -1) {
// Hide the column without affecting the table formatting
$(this).css('visibility', 'hidden');
}
});
// Hide the entire row
$('#tablepress-3 tr:contains("admin-hide")').hide();
});
</script>
```

Comment: Can you provide some of your code?

Comment: Ahh.. a lot of explanation, without any code.

Comment: Added above. My bad. I got caught up in the explanation with showing what I've done.

Comment: so the column you want to hide is not the same where cell contains some specific text?

Comment: The row should be hidden first then the entire column containing the values (essentially making it admin only, unless someone views source).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://codepen.io/SpenserJ/pen/GqviI

```
jQuery(function($) {
  $table = $('#tablepress-3');
  $('th, td', $table).each(function() {
    if ($(this).text().indexOf('Admin Only') !== -1) {
      var index = $(this).index();
      $('th:eq(' + index + '), td:eq(' + index + ')', 'tr', $table).hide();
    }
  });
  // Hide the entire row
  $('tr:contains("Membership Expired")', $table).hide();
});
```

Comment: Great! This hides the row and doesn't break the JQuery/Data Tables functionality. However, it doesn't hide the column. :/

Comment: Do you want it to hide the entire column, or just the data for the column in that row (what I've implemented)?

Comment: The entire column would be great (including header row cell for column). If not, I'll go with this solution.

Comment: @DavidPeters Just updated and it should hide the entire column now. If you are determining what columns should be hidden by the th, you can remove any references to the td, and it should boost performance slightly.

Comment: SpenserJ, you just solved the issue. Way to rock out with your code out. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $('#tableID tr').filter(function() {
        $('td', this).each(function() {
            if ($(this).text().indexOf('admin-hide') != -1)
                $('#tableID tr td:eq('+ $(this).index() +')').hide();
        });

        return $(this).text().indexOf('non-member') != -1;
    }).addClass('disabled');
});
```

Comment: Close, but the explanation requests adding a class to the row (done) and hiding the _column_ that contains 'admin-hide'.

Comment: @SpenserJ - True, edited! Should now hide all td's with the same index as any td containing "admin-hide", which should remove the entire "column" !

Comment: See attempt in Original post. Thanks. Unsure if processing order, due to using Wordpress shortcode, is causing the issue.

Comment: @DavidPeters - Shortcodes generate PHP, which is done on the serverside, so that doesn't matter for javascript, which executes on the clientside, but you will have to change the selector to match the ID of your table.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
// tr that contains the specific word - add class to
$('#tableid tr:contains("specific word")').addClass('yourclass');
// get column index of admin-hide
var index = $('#tableid td:contains("admin-hide")').index();
// and hide all th/tr in that column    
// this is assuming when you initialized datatables you named it oTable as in var oTable = $('table').datatables()
oTable.fnSetColumnVis( index, false ); // for datatables

// or if you want to manually hide them
$('th,td', '#tableid').filter(':nth-child('+(index+1)+')').css('visibility','hidden');
```

If you are using dataTables - you can set visibility like this example.  Also remove the +1 because the index for the method is 0 based also - http://www.datatables.net/examples/api/show_hide.html

[using oTable](http://jsfiddle.net/hSfe8/)

[manually hiding visibility](http://jsfiddle.net/fL55d/)

[using hide() works fine](http://jsfiddle.net/YkUk2/) - i don't know why it was messing up your sorting

```
$('th,td', '#tablepress-demo').filter(':nth-child(' + (index + 1) + ')').hide()
```

Comment: This hides the row! :) However, it causes the sorting features from Tablepress/Data-Tables to disappear.

Comment: hmm I've never worked with that plugin before.. Let me test it out

Comment: @DavidPeters it's just using the regular datatables right?  You can set column visibility using the .fnSetColumnVis() method

Comment: Regular datatables according to the Plugin author.

Comment: @DavidPeters ah.. both methods should work fine for you then.. using datatables built in method or the jQuery method

Answer (score -1):

```
$('table .classForRowThatCouldBeHidden').find('.someClassForHiddenValue').parent().hide();
```

Comment: i'm curious too to know :) .it might be interresting :)

Comment: I'd assume it was downvoted because it doesn't meet any of the requirements. The row isn't hidden based on a class, it is hidden based on textual values.